# Lenovo Legion Y720 wifi device not ready. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, lenovo

I just installed 14.04.
I was having an issue where when I did `rfkill list all` it showed that there was a hard lock on ideapad wifi.  So i followed a solution to blacklist the module idepad_laptop
[Wifi doesnt work on fresh ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893384/wifi-doesnt-work-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-04)

Now the network manager menu shows that the wifi device is not ready.  What should I do.

```
ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:e1:ad:43:5d:49
          inet addr:137.148.94.131  Bcast:137.148.94.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56e1:adff:fe43:5d49/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14691 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9057 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12612219 (12.6 MB)  TX bytes:1430682 (1.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:183101 (183.1 KB)  TX bytes:183101 (183.1 KB)
```

.

```
iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
           eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

.
You can see below that ideapad_wlan and ideapad_bluetooth do not show up anymore

```
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0827]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

.
when i do demsg it shows a bunch of messages showing this

```
...
[ 2057.256949] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[ 2062.604694] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[ 2068.605202] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[ 2073.952924] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[ 2079.953063] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[ 2085.305212] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[ 2091.305695] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[ 2096.657808] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
exit
```

Also update the firmware:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and let us hear the result.