# Attempting to install ubuntu 18.04 for dual boot with windows 10 home non functional

Tags: software-installation

I've been trying many times now to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a new Lenovo Y520 machine with Windows 10 home pre-installed. The windows install is on the original SSD. I added another SSD for the Ubuntu install and operation. After downloaded the amd64 (desktop) iso image and using rufus 3.1 to build flash driver image, things do not go as described in the many instruction flows I can find on the web.

First thing, I created a 20GB open space on the Windows SSD (disk 1, the new ssd is disk 0). The ubuntu flash drive seems to function OK when I boot into it and "try ubuntu" instead of install" Grub comes right up and asks to try, or install.

Bringing up Gparted to setup petitions as described in various install instructions, only disk0 (the new ssd with nothing on it) shows up. That is the first clue to me things are not going well.

So skip that, try again, at grub select install ubuntu. Ok, that process starts, but never get the option to "install alongside windows" which some instruct to for dual boot operation. So, skip that and choose something else and manually setup portions as instructed. The install seems to be going well. I setup a userid and password, initialize wifi connection with my network. Reboot using F12/powerup, select the new ssd (disk0) and login, then the desktop basically freezes when trying to run anything. I can start up terminal. First command, a few seconds- freeze. Cannot shut down, must use power button.

OK, try another tack. Completely wipe the usb drive. Do a complete format the slow way on windows. Then build the boot flash drive again with a new download of amd64 version. Load up with Rufus again. This time boot into Ubuntu USB drive as before. This time select install and select the Erase entire drive option (after creating a windows recovery drive). Since ubuntu seems only capable of seeing the new empty SSD, seems low risk. OK, go through all the steps again, same response. After reboot, no wifi, lockup.

Reboot again with wired LAN connection. Ubuntu says I have network connection, however attempt to start firefox- lockup.

This is taking way way too many hours to get working.

With the wired LAN connect, I tried apt-get, you guessed it- lock up, power cycle.

Oh yes, on the SSD disk1 (windows) not being recognized, I matched the usb boot drive format to the drive partition type (GUID) of the 20GB partition on disk1 (windows SSD).

Since the new SSD (disk0) is empty, I'm not finding what type UEFI, or GUID.

Maybe this is not possible on Windows10 home? Need pro? just a wag.

Please somebody help.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- In BIOS change STA config from RAID to AHCI:  https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Lenovo-Legion-Y520-Linux-Support/td-p/3694784. Also see this: [Install dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 and RAID on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on)
- Read this for WiFi: [Wifi doesnt work on fresh ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893384/wifi-doesnt-work-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thank you for responding and the suggestions. At one point before acquiring this machine I may have found that same thread. Now of course I forgot about it. I think the switch to AHCI was attempted and that caused other problems. I'll go back and study that thread!

Comment: Can somebody explain does Ubuntu require AHCI sata controller mode and why? The machine I have came with NVMe ssd with windows 10 preinstalled. The sata ssd added is in the sata slot normally used for HDD which would have the windows install. When I change sata mode to AHCI, the machine no longer recognizes the windows (NVMe) boot drive and hangs. Are there any recommendations.

Comment: See additional link in answer for RAID vs AHCI.