# Lenovo IdeaPad S145: Touchpad not working

Tags: kernel, touchpad, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo IdeaPad S145 to notice that the touchpad is not working.

There are quite a few similar questions here reporting problems with Lenovo touchpads and Ubuntu but none of the suggested solutions work for me (so far).

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with  5.3.0-45-generic kernel.

This is what `xinput list` shows me:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And here is the content of `/proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=4023 Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input1:1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0002/0003:046D:4023.0003/input/input21
U: Uniq=4023-00-00-00-00
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event4 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=12001f
B: KEY=3f000301ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bfd4444600000000 1 130ff38b17c007 ffff7bfad941dfff ffbeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: REL=1040
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=4054 Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech Wireless Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input1:2
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0002/0003:046D:4054.0004/input/input22
U: Uniq=4054-00-00-00-00
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=ffff0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input23
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=13d3 Product=5a08 Version=1705
N: Name="Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input24
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input25
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input26
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input28
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input29
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input30
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input31
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input32
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=11"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input33
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event16 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=12"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input34
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event17 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

Things I already tried:

- I tried to install `synaptics` driver as stated in https://askubuntu.com/a/1117725, resulting in not a single input device working anymore...
- I altered the grub config as stated in https://askubuntu.com/a/1041835, but it had no noticeable effect
- This answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1052566) seemed promising and I even made it to compile a new kernel. I used `acpidump` to detect my touchpad's id (`ELAN0633`). Checking the list for 'supported' ids (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/input/elan-i2c-ids.h) revealed that the list indeed stops at `ELAN0632` and it seemed obvious that adding `ELAN0633` to the list and compiling a new kernel would solve the problem.

After booting into the my compiled kernel, the touchpad did not work either, but I noticed that  the new kernel had a small effect: Pressing `Fn + F6` now shoes an 'actived' touchpad symbol - using the stock kernel `Fn + F6` always showed a crossed touchpad symbol. The new kernel seems to detect something identified as a touchpad, but cannot use it as an input device yet...

Any ideas how to investigate this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a solution on Reddit:

Patch your kernel using `dkms` and set boot parameters according to [this repo](https://github.com/pavlepiramida/elan_i2c_dkms) and you have a working touchpad. Works with Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 5.3.0-45-generic.

See also the [chat on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/f9h0q4/touchpad_issue_lenovo_s14515iil/fmg277m).

Answer (score 2):

Okay,
so here is my solution after 100s of tries with various kernels and what not.

I installed ubuntu and I changed kernel version as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165594/1138441).
But as mentioned in the same question, I was able to either get touchpad working or wifi. Not both.

I tried ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, fedora, linux mint, Pop_OS! but all had same results, fedora had wifi working and all others couldn't detect wifi or touchpad.

Then, I went ahead and started with fresh installation of ubuntu 20.04, and removing all other OS except windows in dual boot.
During installation touchpad and wireless weren't working.(You can enable/disable - Install 3rd party wifi drivers etc during installation, doesn't have much effect).

Just after installation, restart and boot first time into ubuntu, also make sure you USB tether your laptop for internet access, as it would say **Ubuntu 20.04 has updates to be downloaded, download those updates, and restart**, once done. This enabled my wifi.

I after few days got a message from senior coworker about this same question, so I thought let's give it another try. And **I went ahead to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change this line:**

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`"

to this

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs quiet splash"`

but i didn't install dkms patch mentioned, and as always, after reboot it enabled the touchpad. Even this did enable the touchpad during previous tries but then I was stuck with wifi issues, so remember adding this will definitely enable touchpad in most cases.

Credits :
[reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/f9h0q4/touchpad_issue_lenovo_s14515iil/fmg277m)

Comment: The grub solution solves the touchpad, and installing the hwe kernel (5.8) the wifi works.