# No wifi/ethernet on fresh Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, ethernet

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my new T470 and I cannot connect to the internet, can't see the wifi networks and wired Ethernet. I couldn't solve the problem with the suggestions on the internet.

```
$ ifconfig
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
```

Comment: Your computer is too new to be supported by 14.04. Install 16.04 and all should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi not working (Intel) on HP Spectre x360 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858546/wifi-not-working-intel-on-hp-spectre-x360-13)

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858546/wifi-not-working-intel-on-hp-spectre-x360-13 Your exact same device and therefore the exact same answer.

Comment: @chili555 it is not a very good idea to install the 4.8 kernel to 14.04. I see no reason to use 14.04 with new hardware.

Answer (score 4):

Install Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and your wireless adapter will immediately work.

Your hardware `Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)` is not supported by the 14.04 Ubuntu release.

Comment: Will the LTS kernel backported from Xenial to Trusty (14.04.5) work too?

Comment: @DavidFoerster No, it won't. Trusty won't go beyond the 4.4.