# Wifi card is not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I kind of know the problem, it is the same problem answered by @chili555: [Wifi not working (Intel) on HP Spectre x360 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858546/wifi-not-working-intel-on-hp-spectre-x360-13)

Due to I'm working with ROS Indigo, I have to stick with 14.04.5, and mine wifi card is the same:
**Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)**

but my subsystem is not Device 1010, it's:
**Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 9010**

Can i use the same solution provided by chili555? or is there anything else I need to download and install.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the technique will work well. The question, however, is whether ROS Indigo will work with a 4.8-xx kernel version. If it does not, you can certainly boot back into your old kernel at the GRUB menu and remove the 4.8-xx that you just installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using backports before using the EOL 4.8 kernel

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.14-rc2/backports-4.14-rc2-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-4.14-rc2-1.tar.gz
cd backports-4.14-rc2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and edit your question to add results for

```
dmesg | grep firm
```

Answer (score 0):

The backport worked with some additional steps:

1. During `make install` there are some errors/warnings indicating can't read private key which were ignored as the modules were build without any signing process.
2. The iwlwifi driver was not finding the required firmware for my wlan card, so I searched through to find out what card was used in my laptop, and then downloaded the required firmware from the [Linux* Support for Intel Wireless Adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) website.