# 16.04.5 - Wifi not working Matebook X Pro

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless

I've been having problems getting wi-fi to work on my Huawei Matebook X Pro with Ubuntu 16.04.5 .  The problem seems to be similar to the one found here, [Wifi not working (Intel) on HP Spectre x360 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858546/wifi-not-working-intel-on-hp-spectre-x360-13), but one of the links to a firmware download is dead. Also, that answer is for 14.04 - is it suitable for 16.04?

`iwconfig` output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

bnep0     no wireless extensions.
```

relevant `lspci -v` output:

```
3c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
Subsystem: Device 19e5:3e02
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at 93000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05dc:a838 Lexar Media, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:03c0 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo lshw -c Network -sanitize' output:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
   version: 78
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:93000000-93001fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: bnep0
   serial: [REMOVED]
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes ip=[REMOVED] multicast=yes
```

`arch` output: `x86_64`

Thank you.

edit 11/9/18 4:10pm:

`uname -r` output:

```
4.15.0-38-generic
```

BUT also, someone helped me troubleshoot IRL, we did a kernel update, and the wifi now works, so I guess this problem can be closed.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu,

Comment: The device is supported in kernel version 4.15. Let's see what happens when you load it and check the log: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmeg | grep iwl`

Answer (score 1):

My solution for the Huawei Matebook X Pro, linux-kernel version 4.16, is the following:

1. Determine the name of your Wifi-Device (mine was `Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265`)
2. Download the appropriate Firmware files (similar numbers also work) from the [Intel Website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)
3. Unpack the `.ucode` file and put it in the folder `/lib/firmware`
4. Reboot your system

It should work immediately after the last step.